# Which financial database has the most extensive coverage of person-level data and uses person-level identifiers

Tags: bloomberg

For some empirical research, I need to retrieve data relating to the board members of companies corresponding to all securities in a major index.

The data points I am looking for include gender, tenure, age, etc.

I am now wondering which financial database service is most suited to this kind of research. I have experimented with Bloomberg, but while the "COMPANY_BOARD_MEMBERS" field returns some such data items, there is no way to access the unique person identifier used by Bloomberg internally to retrieve other data points.

Unfortunately, the public documentations of Bloomberg, Datastream, Reuters Eikon and the like are not helpful at all with regard to this question.

While I am aware that the data I am looking for are not themselves financial data, I nonetheless post this question here because (1) the data are needed for empirical work in finance, and (2) the databases are financial databases, familiarity with which is most reasonable to assume on Quant SE.

Any experiences you might have with retrieving this sort of data would be much appreciated.

Please note that this question is not opinion based, for example, Bloomberg is objectively bad at retrieving person-level data because no accessible personal identifier exists. A database where this is the case would be much more suitable. Also, the number of biographical data points available is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise at all, but a few things I've come across in passing are [ExuComp](http://marketintelligence.spglobal.com/documents/products/Compustat_ExecuComp_v2.pdf) and [BoardEx](http://corp.boardex.com/data/). They might have the info you're looking for? If you're an academic, both are available on Wharton Research Database Services.